# How to replace the elements of an RDD

Tags: java, list, iterator, apache-spark

I have an RDD like so:

`JavaPairRDD<SubspaceFlag, Iterable<Point>> flagPointPairs`

Example value:

`(01), [(5, 5), (6, 1), (7, 2), (9, 4)]`

`Point` is an (x, y) point in a two-dimensional space

I need to remove some elements from the `Iterable<Point>` part of the `Tuple2`. For example I need to keep only the points that *dominate* the others `(x1 <= x2 AND y1 < y2 OR y1 <= y2 AND x1 < x2)`.

In the end I am left with a temporary list `[(5, 5), (6, 1)]` which I want to convert back to `JavaPairRDD<SubspaceFlag, Iterable<Point>>` -> `(01), [(5, 5), (6, 1)]`.

I know how to access the `Iterable<Point>`, I know how to make the smaller list that interests me from the `Iterable<Point>`, but I don't know how to make that list back to an RDD with it's accompanying `SubspaceFlag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDDs are immutable structures, hence you don't replace elements in an RDD, you transform an RDD into another.
In this specific case, the `rdd.map` tranformation will allow you to apply a function to each element of the RDD, resulting in a new RDD.

Given

```
val flagPointPairsRdd:RDD[SubspaceFlag, Iterable[Point]] = ???
```

and a function:

```
def dominants(points: Iterable[Point]):Iterable[Point] = ??? //Your impl here
```

Then you can obtain the desired outcome by:

```
val dominatingPairsRdd = flagPointPairs.map{case (flag, points) => (flag, dominants(points))}
```

The equivalent Java code is fairly similar (only more verbose) and left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would have prefered it to be in Java since the question is in Java. It is no big deal though, I also posted it in Java since it is quite different.

Comment: I often recommend to learn the small bit of Scala that is needed to work with Spark. It makes your life a lot easier and you can quickly test code/jobs/ideas in the Spark-shell.

Comment: You are right, for me it is more a situation of "I don't want to get out of my comfort zone" since I have used Java a lot but I will probably go to Scala sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

@maasg's answer is pretty much what I needed to know (that in order to return the same type of RDD back I should just map it) but since my question is in Java and the answer in Java is quite different I will post the answer in Java as well.

Having an RDD like so:

`JavaPairRDD<SubspaceFlag, Iterable<Point>> flagPointPairs = ...`

In order to return the same type of RDD but with different values first you need a method like so:

```
private Iterable<Point> localSkylines(Iterable<Point> pointIterable) {
        List<Point> localSkylines = new ArrayList<>();

        // find local skylines here

        return localSkylines;
    }
```

And then you can make the new RDD like so:

`JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Iterable<Point>> dominatingPairs = flagPointPairs.mapToPair(fp -> new Tuple2(fp._1, localSkylines(fp._2)));`

The major key differences here are two:

1. In Java in order to get back a `JavaPairRDD` you must use `.mapToPair()` and use `new Tuple2(left, right)`
2. In order to return an `Iterable<Point>` you don't need to convert the `List<Point>` since it is an `Iterable<Point>` already.

Comment: re: (1): Indeed -> As I mentioned, the Java API is more verbose. In Scala, implicit conversions take a lot of that boilerplate away from your code. re: (2) No difference. That function will work the same in both Java and Scala.

Comment: @maasg About (1) you are right it's just more verbose but I included it since someone might get the same headaches as I did trying to get used to having two different functions because of the way the API works in Java. 

About (2) I mentioned it just in case someone thinks that he might need to a conversion from `List` to `Iterable`. He might think that because I implied it on my question, so in case someone tries to make the same mistake as I did he can just see that there is no need for conversion (I was trying for around 15 minutes to convert it before I realized how stupid I was).

Comment: Always a good thing to leave the lessons learned for reference of future users (or future self :-) )